# Use virtual camera on physical device android studio

Tags: android-studio, virtual-camera

I have already connected my physical android device via android studio. Is there any way to emulate camera like a virtual emulator does but on physical device?

I thought physical connected device would still work like an emulated device. I wanted to save memory debugging an android app. I tried reading docs on adb and other stuff but It seems like the feature is limited to app debugging.